# Error "Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined"

Tags: xml, odoo-10, erp, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have odoo11 installed on AWS. I am trying to add fields in "kanban view" but I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined" when trying to define kanban view.

So how to solve this issue? or what is the correct way to do that?

Here is the code below:

```
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="customer_analysis.kanb">
  <field name="name">Servays.kanb</field>
  <field name="model">customer_analysis.anaylsis</field>
  <field name="priority">10</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <kanban>
          <field name="customer"/>
          <field name="represent"/>
          <field name="phone"/>
          <field name="location"/>
          <field name="position"/>
          <field name="package"/> 
    </kanban>
  </field>
</record>
```

the error occurs with the code above when trying to show some details in it and when I comment the above code "empty kanban" appears.

```
 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="customer_analysis.action_window">
  <field name="name">Servays</field> 
  <field name="res_model">customer_analysis.anaylsis</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form,pivot</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="customer_analysis.tree"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Create an Analysis, a step of a new opportunity.
          </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="customer_analysis.kanb">
  <field name="name">Servays.kanb</field>
  <field name="model">customer_analysis.anaylsis</field>
  <field name="priority">10</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <kanban>
          <templates>
           <t t-name="kanban-box">
             <field name="customer"/>
             <field name="represent"/>
             <field name="phone"/>
             <field name="location"/>
             <field name="position"/>
             <field name="package"/> 
           </t>
        </templates>
    </kanban>
  </field>
</record>
```

Please, try this it would be helpful to locate the kanban view.